# Is every irreducible unitary class one representation induced?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected semi simple Lie group with finite center. 
Fix a maximal compact subgroup $K$. 
An irreducible representation $(\pi,V)$ of $G$ is called a "class-one representation", if it contains non-zero $K$-fixed vectors. It is often treated as well-known, at least for splitrank one groups,  that every irreducible unitary class-one representation is either trivial or infinitesimally equivalent to a representation induced from a minimal parabolic (and not only a sub representation of the latter as the sub representation theorem says).

Where can I find a proof of this "well-known"?

Comment: As stated, it si false: the trivil representation of $G$ is an example, which is not induced from a minimal parabolic subgroup

Comment: Yes ok, sorry, let's add the conditions of $G$ being connected and exclude the trivial representation. I update the question.

Comment: The paper by Barbasch and Baldoni Silva (see the math reviews http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=696689) answers this for all rank one groups; special cases were done by Hirai earlier

Comment: It's probably not trivial to extract the class-one case from the paper (or its references), but anyway it's freely available via GDZ: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002099276

Comment: P.S. Are you only asking about split rank 1, or is your "well known" supposed to apply more generally?

Comment: In the papers it is used for rank one groups, but the formulation was vague, indicating it might be true more generally.